# How do I use ViewModelViewHost in a ListView ItemTemplate with ReactiveUI and Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, ios, listview, xamarin, reactiveui

I am trying to use ReactiveUI with Xamarin Forms and am running into some difficulty getting View Model Location to work in a ListView that has an ItemTemplate.

I have registered the View and ViewModel in the AppBootstrapper.cs with the following line:

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => 
    new MonkeyCellView(), typeof(IViewFor<MonkeyCellViewModel>));
```

I have also referenced the `ReactiveUI.XamForms` namespace in the XAML and wrapped the `ViewModelViewHost` in a `Page` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="XamarinFormsReactiveListView.Views.MonkeyListView" 
    xmlns:rui="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI.XamForms;assembly=ReactiveUI.XamForms">
<StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="AddMonkey" Text="Add Monkey"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" x:Name="MonkeyList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Page>
                            <rui:ViewModelViewHost x:Name="vmvh" ViewModel="{Binding .}" />
                        </Page>
                    </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

*NOTE: You have to wrap the ViewModelViewHost in a Page element because that is the only element supported by ReactiveUI with Xamarin Forms for ViewModelViewHost at this time, as per this file:*

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI.XamForms/XamForms/ActivationForViewFetcher.cs

When I run the **XamarinFormsReactiveListView.iOS** project I get the following error message in the InnerException of a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:

> Don't know how to detect when ReactiveUI.XamForms.ViewModelViewHost is activated/deactivated, you may need to implement IActivationForViewFetcher

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had it a bit wrong, and should instead have been referencing my own class `MonkeyCellView : ViewCell, IViewFor<MonkeyCellViewModel>` inside the DataTemplate and binding it's ViewModel to the current item with `<views:MonkeyCellView ViewModel="{Binding .}"/>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="XamarinFormsReactiveListView.Views.MonkeyListView" 
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsReactiveListView.Views;assembly=XamarinFormsReactiveListView">
<StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="AddMonkey" Text="Add Monkey"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" x:Name="MonkeyList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:MonkeyCellView ViewModel="{Binding .}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```